# Windows 2008 concurrent TCPIP connections

Tags: networking, tcp, windows-server-2008

In Windows XP, Microsoft took the decision to limit the number of half open connections in later service packs. Patching tcpip.sys was rumoured to fix this. Does such a limit exist in Windows 2008, and if so, is it configurable?

Comment: I hope not, as there's not much point in a server that can only handle 10 active connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Vista SP1 shipped, there was some article about the alignment with Windows Server 2008, and their example was the networking subsystem, and they said something like that it is designed to handle thousands of connections. So I guess, no, they won't limit it to 10 :)

I think it was [this article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709618.aspx) (scroll to bottom), though I think I remember it being longer.